# Picking a random SelectedIndex from a combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working on a project for class, and I'm finished with what's required. However, I wanted to go the extra mile and I'm curious for myself.

I have a combo box with items in it.

1. Turque
2. Runners
3. Parkade
4. ABM
5. Homo Milk
6. Gasbar
7. Donair
8. Fire Hall
9. Serviette
10. Turfed Out
11. Forty-Pounder
12. Twenty-Sixer or Twixer
13. Hooped

So far I have an output for what the user selects. Without pasting the whole code...

```
Private Sub btnResults3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnResults3.Click
     If cboCanadianisms.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        txtResults.Text = "A knitted cap/hat, referred to as a beanie in the United States. A beanie is a completely different type of hat in Canada. "
    ElseIf cboCanadianisms.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        txtResults.Text = "Referred to as sneakers or tennis shoes in the United States."
```

and so on and so on.

**My question** - Is there a way to make a second button to show a random selection with the attached text.

**Code**

```
txtResults.Text = "You have chosen " & 
cboCanadianisms.Items.Item(myRandom.Next(i)).ToString
```

but this only shows one of the 13 items from the combo box without the attached text.

thanks

Comment: If an answer sorts out your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to the answer - It makes sure that the user gets reputation points and makes it easier for anyone else who has the same problem to see that your question has an accepted answer that might work for them as well. (And the person answering the question gets reputation points btw)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the text value of the bounded item in your select / combo box?

```
Dim randomNumber As Integer = myRandom.Next(i); 
txtResults.Text = "You have chosen " & 
cboCanadianisms.Items.Item(randomNumber ).ToString & cboCanadianisms.Items.Item(randomNumber ).Text;
```

Comment: What is the "(i)" ? Studio tells me it's not declared.

Comment: I assumed you had declared it previously as per the code you provided
cboCanadianisms.Items.Item(myRandom.Next(i)).ToString

but you can use the another myRandom.Next() which takes no arguments but you will have to check that the generated number is within the bounds of your combo box...between 0 - 12 (I assume VB is also zero based). Please note this is to show the concept as opposed to giving an answer, I'm not a VB programmer and did not check if the code compiles against vbc.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I don't have a VB compiler right now, so there might be some errors in this code)

First of all, you shouldn't rely on the `SelectedIndex` in your methods, as it will break completely if someone where to add something to the top of the list. Ideally, you should create a class that consists of `Title` and `Description`, and use that - but that might be for another extra mile :)

First, let's modify your code to support what you want to achieve. Instead of having the code that displays the description inside the event handler, we create a method that takes the selected index as argument, and returns the description of that:

```
Function getDescription(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Select Case index
        Case 0:
            Return "A knitted..."
        Case 1:
            Return "Referred to as sn..."
        Case Else:
            Return ""
End Function
```

With this function, we can replace the entire event handler with:

```
txtResults.Text = getDescription(cboCanadianisms.SelectedIndex)
```

Thanks to this, we can use that in the random part of the code as well:

```
Dim number as Integer = myRandom.Next(i)
txtResults.Text = "You have chosen " & cboCanadianisms.Items.Item(number).ToString & ": " & getDescription(number)
```

Comment: Thank you!! After some hair pulling because I didn't want to ask dumb questions I finally got this to work! For some reason the End Function is still underlined green and says "getdescription doesn't return a value on all code paths" but it works and that's good enough for me considering i've spent a few hours now on this and it was just for "fun" ;) thanks again!

Comment: That's because if you pass an integer not in the `Select Case` it won't return anything. I have updated my answer to handle that case.

Comment: that did it! Thanks again, this was great!

Answer (score 0):

A little late but this is my try, I put the `Descriptions` into a list of string (feel free to edit to match your definitions), and make it random by `Random` function:

```
Private Sub btnResults2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnResults2.Click

    Dim Descriptions() As String = {"A knitted cap/hat", "Referred to as sneakers...", "Description 3",
                                "Description 4", "Description 5", "Description 6",
                                "Description 7", "Description 8", "Description 9",
                                "Description 10", "Description 11", "Description 12", "Description 13"}

    Dim ListofDesc As List(Of String) = Descriptions.ToList
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim Selected As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To 13
        count = ListofDesc.Count
        Selected = MyRand.Next(0, count)
        cboCanadianisms.SelectedIndex = Selected
    Next

End Sub
```

I just tried it with a small winforms app, and it shows a new randomly generated selection for the ComboBox each time we press the `btnResults2` button. Hope this helps!